# CoreMl issue with xcode , multiple resources named 'coremldata.bin' in target 'AppModule'

Tags: swift, coreml, mlmodel

I am working on my swift playgrounds project. I added the FitnessMoves.mlmodelc file to my playgrounds project. But the i get the multiple resources named 'coremldata.bin' in target 'AppModule' error from xcode. The error disappears when i change 3 of the names of the coremldata.bin. But when i change the names and try to run my project. It crashes immediately when i press the button which was supposed to open the camera
[The image of the mlmodelc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKi0.png)
The code

```
class var urlOfModelInThisBundle: URL {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        guard let resPath = bundle.url(forResource: "FitnessMoves", withExtension: "mlmodel") else {
            fatalError("FitnessMoves.mlmodel not found in the app bundle. Please ensure the file is added to the bundle.")
        }
        return try! MLModel.compileModel(at: resPath)
    }
```

When i check other persons projects i see that they worked out their code with no problem even though they have the same amount of coremldata.bin files inside their .mlmodelc files
I spent full day trying to sort it out but couldn't find the problem. Grateful for any help.
Here is the full code below

```
//
//  FitnessMoves.swift
//  wwdcFitnessApp
//
//  Created by Omer on 18.04.2023.
//

//
// FitnessMoves.swift
//
// This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

import CoreML


/// Model Prediction Input Type
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
class FitnessMovesInput : MLFeatureProvider {

    /// A sequence of body poses to classify. Its multiarray encoding uses the first dimension to index time over 60 frames. The second dimension indexes x, y, and confidence of pose keypoint locations. The last dimension indexes the keypoint type, ordered as: nose, neck, right shoulder, right elbow, right wrist, left shoulder, left elbow, left wrist, right hip, right knee, right ankle, left hip, left knee, left ankle, right eye, left eye, right ear, left ear as 60 × 3 × 18 3-dimensional array of floats
    var poses: MLMultiArray

    var featureNames: Set<String> {
        get {
            return ["poses"]
        }
    }
    
    func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
        if (featureName == "poses") {
            return MLFeatureValue(multiArray: poses)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    init(poses: MLMultiArray) {
        self.poses = poses
    }

    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    convenience init(poses: MLShapedArray<Float>) {
        self.init(poses: MLMultiArray(poses))
    }

}


/// Model Prediction Output Type
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
class FitnessMovesOutput : MLFeatureProvider {

    /// Source provided by CoreML
    private let provider : MLFeatureProvider

    /// Probability of each category as dictionary of strings to doubles
    var labelProbabilities: [String : Double] {
        return self.provider.featureValue(for: "labelProbabilities")!.dictionaryValue as! [String : Double]
    }

    /// Most likely action category as string value
    var label: String {
        return self.provider.featureValue(for: "label")!.stringValue
    }

    var featureNames: Set<String> {
        return self.provider.featureNames
    }
    
    func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
        return self.provider.featureValue(for: featureName)
    }

    init(labelProbabilities: [String : Double], label: String) {
        self.provider = try! MLDictionaryFeatureProvider(dictionary: ["labelProbabilities" : MLFeatureValue(dictionary: labelProbabilities as [AnyHashable : NSNumber]), "label" : MLFeatureValue(string: label)])
    }

    init(features: MLFeatureProvider) {
        self.provider = features
    }
}


/// Class for model loading and prediction
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
class FitnessMoves {
    let model: MLModel

    /// URL of model assuming it was installed in the same bundle as this class
    class var urlOfModelInThisBundle: URL {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        guard let resPath = bundle.url(forResource: "FitnessMoves", withExtension: "mlmodel") else {
            fatalError("FitnessMoves.mlmodel not found in the app bundle. Please ensure the file is added to the bundle.")
        }
        return try! MLModel.compileModel(at: resPath)
    }


    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance with an existing MLModel object.

        Usually the application does not use this initializer unless it makes a subclass of FitnessMoves.
        Such application may want to use `MLModel(contentsOfURL:configuration:)` and `FitnessMoves.urlOfModelInThisBundle` to create a MLModel object to pass-in.

        - parameters:
          - model: MLModel object
    */
    init(model: MLModel) {
        self.model = model
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance by automatically loading the model from the app's bundle.
    */
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.")
    convenience init() {
        try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
    }

    /**
        Construct a model with configuration

        - parameters:
           - configuration: the desired model configuration

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem
    */
    convenience init(configuration: MLModelConfiguration) throws {
        try self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle, configuration: configuration)
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance with explicit path to mlmodelc file
        - parameters:
           - modelURL: the file url of the model

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem
    */
    convenience init(contentsOf modelURL: URL) throws {
        try self.init(model: MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL))
    }

    /**
        Construct a model with URL of the .mlmodelc directory and configuration

        - parameters:
           - modelURL: the file url of the model
           - configuration: the desired model configuration

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem
    */
    convenience init(contentsOf modelURL: URL, configuration: MLModelConfiguration) throws {
        try self.init(model: MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL, configuration: configuration))
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance asynchronously with optional configuration.

        Model loading may take time when the model content is not immediately available (e.g. encrypted model). Use this factory method especially when the caller is on the main thread.

        - parameters:
          - configuration: the desired model configuration
          - handler: the completion handler to be called when the model loading completes successfully or unsuccessfully
    */
    @available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
    class func load(configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration(), completionHandler handler: @escaping (Swift.Result<FitnessMoves, Error>) -> Void) {
        return self.load(contentsOf: self.urlOfModelInThisBundle, configuration: configuration, completionHandler: handler)
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance asynchronously with optional configuration.

        Model loading may take time when the model content is not immediately available (e.g. encrypted model). Use this factory method especially when the caller is on the main thread.

        - parameters:
          - configuration: the desired model configuration
    */
    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    class func load(configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration()) async throws -> FitnessMoves {
        return try await self.load(contentsOf: self.urlOfModelInThisBundle, configuration: configuration)
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance asynchronously with URL of the .mlmodelc directory with optional configuration.

        Model loading may take time when the model content is not immediately available (e.g. encrypted model). Use this factory method especially when the caller is on the main thread.

        - parameters:
          - modelURL: the URL to the model
          - configuration: the desired model configuration
          - handler: the completion handler to be called when the model loading completes successfully or unsuccessfully
    */
    @available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
    class func load(contentsOf modelURL: URL, configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration(), completionHandler handler: @escaping (Swift.Result<FitnessMoves, Error>) -> Void) {
        MLModel.load(contentsOf: modelURL, configuration: configuration) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                handler(.failure(error))
            case .success(let model):
                handler(.success(FitnessMoves(model: model)))
            }
        }
    }

    /**
        Construct FitnessMoves instance asynchronously with URL of the .mlmodelc directory with optional configuration.

        Model loading may take time when the model content is not immediately available (e.g. encrypted model). Use this factory method especially when the caller is on the main thread.

        - parameters:
          - modelURL: the URL to the model
          - configuration: the desired model configuration
    */
    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    class func load(contentsOf modelURL: URL, configuration: MLModelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration()) async throws -> FitnessMoves {
        let model = try await MLModel.load(contentsOf: modelURL, configuration: configuration)
        return FitnessMoves(model: model)
    }

    /**
        Make a prediction using the structured interface

        - parameters:
           - input: the input to the prediction as FitnessMovesInput

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem

        - returns: the result of the prediction as FitnessMovesOutput
    */
    func prediction(input: FitnessMovesInput) throws -> FitnessMovesOutput {
        return try self.prediction(input: input, options: MLPredictionOptions())
    }

    /**
        Make a prediction using the structured interface

        - parameters:
           - input: the input to the prediction as FitnessMovesInput
           - options: prediction options

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem

        - returns: the result of the prediction as FitnessMovesOutput
    */
    func prediction(input: FitnessMovesInput, options: MLPredictionOptions) throws -> FitnessMovesOutput {
        let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input, options:options)
        return FitnessMovesOutput(features: outFeatures)
    }

    /**
        Make a prediction using the convenience interface

        - parameters:
            - poses: A sequence of body poses to classify. Its multiarray encoding uses the first dimension to index time over 60 frames. The second dimension indexes x, y, and confidence of pose keypoint locations. The last dimension indexes the keypoint type, ordered as: nose, neck, right shoulder, right elbow, right wrist, left shoulder, left elbow, left wrist, right hip, right knee, right ankle, left hip, left knee, left ankle, right eye, left eye, right ear, left ear as 60 × 3 × 18 3-dimensional array of floats

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem

        - returns: the result of the prediction as FitnessMovesOutput
    */
    func prediction(poses: MLMultiArray) throws -> FitnessMovesOutput {
        let input_ = FitnessMovesInput(poses: poses)
        return try self.prediction(input: input_)
    }

    /**
        Make a prediction using the convenience interface

        - parameters:
            - poses: A sequence of body poses to classify. Its multiarray encoding uses the first dimension to index time over 60 frames. The second dimension indexes x, y, and confidence of pose keypoint locations. The last dimension indexes the keypoint type, ordered as: nose, neck, right shoulder, right elbow, right wrist, left shoulder, left elbow, left wrist, right hip, right knee, right ankle, left hip, left knee, left ankle, right eye, left eye, right ear, left ear as 60 × 3 × 18 3-dimensional array of floats

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem

        - returns: the result of the prediction as FitnessMovesOutput
    */

    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    func prediction(poses: MLShapedArray<Float>) throws -> FitnessMovesOutput {
        let input_ = FitnessMovesInput(poses: poses)
        return try self.prediction(input: input_)
    }

    /**
        Make a batch prediction using the structured interface

        - parameters:
           - inputs: the inputs to the prediction as [FitnessMovesInput]
           - options: prediction options

        - throws: an NSError object that describes the problem

        - returns: the result of the prediction as [FitnessMovesOutput]
    */
    func predictions(inputs: [FitnessMovesInput], options: MLPredictionOptions = MLPredictionOptions()) throws -> [FitnessMovesOutput] {
        let batchIn = MLArrayBatchProvider(array: inputs)
        let batchOut = try model.predictions(from: batchIn, options: options)
        var results : [FitnessMovesOutput] = []
        results.reserveCapacity(inputs.count)
        for i in 0..<batchOut.count {
            let outProvider = batchOut.features(at: i)
            let result =  FitnessMovesOutput(features: outProvider)
            results.append(result)
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

I tried changing the names , tried rebuilding the coreML file on CreateML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found. In the updated playgrounds app there is no more need for .mlmodelc files. The app can compile the .mlmodel files

Comment: How? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Dc7 I am afraid I don't remember the problem at all now.